# How to make a props function optional

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I know you can make props optional with a ?, like this:

```
type: 'goal' | 'course',
onSaveCourse?: (title: string, date: Date) => void;
onSaveGoal?: (text: string) => void;
```

But if the prop is a function(as in the snippet above) typescript complains, once such a function is called, that it won't put up with "possibly undefined".

How could this be resolved?

**Motivation of the above snippet:**
It's an edit modal that should be used in two cases ( 'goal' | 'course')
and I don't want to be forced to pass the onSave function I don't need for either case.

Comment: Just wrap your assignments / usages in a `if (props.myProp)`, otherwise, don't make them optional. Either they are, or they're not.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have an typings as below with optional functions:

```
interface Props {
  type: 'goal' | 'course'
  onSaveCourse?: (title: string, date: Date) => void
  onSaveGoal?: (text: string) => void
}
```

You can safely use them as:

```js
props.onSaveCourse?.('abc', someDate)
props.onSaveGoal?.('abc')
```

As [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining#optional_chaining_with_function_calls) is also possible with function calls. Using this will not call the function when it is `null` or `undefined` and TypeScript will also not complain.

Answer (score 3):

You can make a type like this:

```
type YourProps = {
    type: 'goal',
    onSaveGoal: (text: string) => void;
} | {
    type: 'course',
    onSaveCourse: (title: string, date: Date) => void;
};
```

This will

1. enforce that the `onSaveX` function is set according to the type,
2. Remove the TypeScript error for `possibly undefined`.

Comment: Nice! I didn't know you could have multiple types chained with operators.

Comment: I believe it is better to use unions for props. Because, I'd willing to bet, that if type is course, you are allowed to use only onSaveCourse, It is much safer. You have my upvote